# Replace master branch with entire local tree

Tags: git, version-control

**I have two things I need to combine:**

1. an existing git repository with two years' revision history. For
   complicated reasons beyond my control parts of this branch are
   outdated.
2. A folder tree containing our newest 'Live' code.

What I want is that the new local code *becomes* the master. So if a file has
changed, that changed version becomes the new master version. If there is a new local file, it is added to the repository. If a file is no longer in the local version, it is removed from the master. No merging, resolving or rebasing is required.

I've searched here for the best solution, but found nothing that quite
describes this situation. Either I'm not finding the right keywords, or no-one out there has been stupid enough to make such drastic changes to their sources with occasionally pushing.

**I think the best course of action would be to:**

1. Clone the newest version of master branch.
2. Delete everything I've just cloned except the .git and .gitignore
   files/folders.
3. Drop my new code into that folder.
4. Commit and forcefully push everything.

But I would like to double check before I go ahead and do this. My question to the GIT gurus out is if this would work? Or are there problems
that would come back to haunt me later? Is there a better or simpler way?

I have a complication, in that I have other branches on which there is active
development. They are changes will at some point have to be merged back into the
master. Can I expect a mass of problems when that moment comes?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan will work.
The only issues that I see are when you will merge some other branches, that will have modified old files that you deleted in the master. For these conflicts you will need to decide if will use the branch version or delete them.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the feedback!